# How can I map a Docker containers port to a different number - but not on the host

Tags: docker, docker-compose

For testing purposes I would like to run a cluster of three containers, each running the same service on port 7600. Those containers should reside in one network and could theoretically access each other as `host1:7600`, `host2:7600` and `host3:7600`.

However I want to 'emulate' an external port mapping, such that the service of each container is still bound to port 7600 but that the services can acess each other by maped (different) ports like `host1:8881`, `host2:8882` and `host3:8883`.

How can I do that as easily as possible - preferred within a Docker Compose setup.

The reasoning is that I want to test how the service will behave with a configuration of three physical hosts running that service and mapped its port to an arbitrary external port.

Following some *edits* to clarify the task, after the first comments won't met the requirements (however thank you for every answer).

- **I can't use VMs**, as the Test is already running within VirtualBox with no ability to get nested VT-x running.
- I would neither bind the ports to the host, nor to the same IP address.

Comment: Using separate VMs for each container is probably the best way to test your configuration locally.  It would be the closest approximation to the production environment.

Comment: Thank you @ShawnK for your thougts. I already tried that with Vagrant. Sadly I recognized that this setup won't run within my VirtualBox machine I am already in, because I could not get nested VT-x running :(

Comment: Binding multiple containers to the same host port isn't going to be possible... BUT what about setting up a reverse proxy to mimic the same behavior?  Something like this: https://bobcares.com/blog/docker-multiple-containers-same-port/

Comment: Thanks again. I would not bind the service ports to the same port on one host. I would rather bind them to unique ports. And furthermore I would bind them to their original IP address or better to their alias hostname in a docker network.

Answer (score 1):

After further investigation I found a working solution for me.

The following Docker Compose file shows an example of the solution. It shows how to make two services accessible by an external IP and external port. The example works completely in Docker without the need to run the containers in two separate virtual machines.

The two services are by example two Nginx instances. Imagine both services should access each other by their external IP and port to form a cluster. The external IP and port are emulated by two separate busybox containers mapping the ports of the service containers to their own IP.

```
version: '3'

services:

  service1:
    image: nginx:latest

  service2:
    image: nginx:latest

  proxy1:
    image: busybox:latest
    command: nc -lk -p 8081 -e /bin/nc service1 80
    expose:
      - "8081"

  proxy2:
    image: busybox:latest
    command: nc -lk -p 8082 -e /bin/nc service2 80
    expose:
      - "8082"
```

The services `service1:80` and `service2:80` can access each other by their external representations `proxy1:8081` and `proxy2:8082`